# How to retrieve multiple columns using pluck on form select?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using pluck to retrieve some columns (name & id) and populate on form select. This is my current solution

Controller

```
$shops = DB::table('shops')->pluck('shop_name', 'id');
return View::make('index')->with('shops', $shops)
```

View

```
{{ Form::select('id', $shops, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Output

```
<select class="form-control" name="id">
<option value="1">JDon</option>
<option value="2">Watsons</option>
</select>
```

How about if I want to retrieve 3 columns (name, address & id) and I want to show to the user the shop name & address?

Comment: then pluck 2 attributes, or dont pluck and get what you need. or use a pagination. this question is opinion based.

Comment: You mean shop name and address as the value in dropdown select?

Comment: Here is a direct consequence to the persistent begging boilerplate you're adding to all of your questions: I am more likely to see your question if it contains pleading, and if it is also off-topic then I will vote to close. Thus, while I would rather you read the guidelines on what constitutes an on-topic question, you will be less likely to have your questions closed if you can refrain from begging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$shops = DB::table('shops')
  ->select(DB::raw("CONCAT(shop_name,' ',address) AS shop_full_name"),'id')
  ->pluck('shop_full_name', 'id');
```